# Solution for brownie transact stuck with "Awaiting transaction in the mempool..."?

Tags: brownie

for like every 1 out of 10 transact, it got stuck with a `Awaiting transaction in the mempool...` in terminal.

it just stuck there forever, even if the transaction itself is already confirmed( on blockchain explorer).

I wonder if this is a brownie thing or a web3.py thing?

my evn(Brownie v1.16.4, Web3 5.23.1)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.